# Asp.Net Axaj.BeginForm & UpdateTargetId not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I have this in **HomeController**:

```
public ActionResult Details(string id)
    {
        var customer = Customers.GetCustomersById(id);
        return PartialView("CustomerDetails", customer);
    }
```

And this in **Index.aspx**:

```
<div>
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Details", new AjaxOptions
           {
               UpdateTargetId = "customerDetails",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               HttpMethod = "POST"
           }))
           { %>
        <p>
            Customer:
            <%=Html.DropDownList("id")%></p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Details" /></p>
        <% } %>
    </div>
    <div id="customerDetails">
</div>
```

And finally in **CustomerDetails.ascx** I have:

```
  <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            Name:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Credit:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Credit) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            CustomerID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.CustomerID) %>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <p>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=Model.PrimaryKey */ }) %> |
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </p>
```

CustomerDetails.ascx was generated by right clicking on the Details-method and choosing "Add View", and selecting partial view and strongly typed view.

I'd want this to update the customer details in "Ajax-manner" inside a div called "customerDetails" inside Index.html. The problem is that after pressing Details-button, a new page is opened where with the correct details. The output page has no master page colors or layouts.

If I debug at Details-method, the contents of customer object is correct.

Any help appreciated!

/pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely culprit is that you aren't including MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js on the page.  This causes the javascript to fail because it can't find the necessary functions and the form submits normally instead through Ajax.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is no longer the case as of ASP.NET MVC 3  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782697/are-microsoftajax-js-microsoftmvcajax-js-and-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-obsolete