# Why does Ajax.BeginForm replace my whole page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Context:  Asp.Net MVC3 w/Razor

I am trying to put a login form on a Razor layout (formerly master page) so that, when the user times out, s/he can be prompted to login without being redirected (as in RallyDev).  So, I have created a partial _LogOn.cshtml with all the requisite stuff (username, etc.) inside an Ajax.BeginForm with an UpdateTargetId that points to a div that holds the logon controls inside the ajax form.  The form posts back to the AccountsController.RefreshLogOn action, but obviously, the containing page may have been rendered from a different controller. The RefreshLogOn action returns PartialView("_LogOn").  In any case, my expectation/desire is that only the controls inside this div are replaced.  What is happening instead is that my page location changes to /Accounts/RefreshLogon and the whole page is replaced by the partial.  Is there another approach I should be taking?

Here's the relevant code:

_LogOn.cshtml

```
 @{
        using (Ajax.BeginForm("RefreshLogOn", "Accounts", 
            new AjaxOptions { 
                      OnSuccess = "logonSucceeded", 
                      OnFailure = "logonFailed",         
                      HttpMethod = "Post", 
                      UpdateTargetId = "user-info" }, 
            new { @id = "refresh"}))
        {  
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

       <div id="user-info">
                <p>Your session has expired.</p>
            <div class="error">@Html.ValidationSummary()</div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td>@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Remember Me:</td>
                    <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.RememberMe)</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
        </div>
            }
        }
```

AccountsController

```
public ActionResult RefreshLogOn (LogOnModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            ...content elided...

            return PartialView("_LogOn");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorMessages.IncorrectUsernameOrPassword);
    }

    return PartialView("_LogOn", model);
}
```

Ajax.BeginForm --> form tag generated:

```
<form action="/Accounts/RefreshLogOn" id="refresh" method="post" 
    onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));"
    onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), 
    { 
    insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, 
    httpMethod: &#39;Post&#39;, 
    updateTargetId: &#39;user-info&#39;, 
    onFailure: Function.createDelegate(this, logonFailed), 
    onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, logonSucceeded) 
    });">
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`Ajax.*` helpers in ASP.NET MVC 3 use unobtrusive jquery so make sure that you have referenced the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script in your view. Also you could use [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see what's happening under the scenes and why the form doesn't send an AJAX request.

Also the `UpdateTargetId = "form"` seems suspicious especially when your form has the `refresh` id: `@id = "refresh"`. Is there some other element inside your DOM with `id="form"`? Maybe you meant `UpdateTargetId = "refresh"`?

Comment: Yeah - I know that's a little confusing - my ajax form has the id = "refresh" and my update target, inside the ajax form, has the id = "form" - was going to change that anyway, just in case the word "form" was confusing anything.  But I'm hoping the unobtrusive-ajax tip is the key.  Will report back shortly - thanks!

Comment: Sadly, no joy.  What I am seeing is that the form tag generated by the Ajax helper is targeting the MicrosoftAjax libraries, not unobtrusive javascript.  I am updating the post to show the generated form tag.  The Helpers I have are in System.Web.Mvc.dll v4.0.30319. Should I have something else?

Comment: @sydneyos, if you think that the Ajax helper is using MicsoroftAjax then you need to include those libraries. And let me give you an advice: get rid of this crap and use jquery.

Comment: Also note, I have UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = false in my web.config as my form validation in another page started to fail with that set to true.  But I did have those libraries (Microsoftxxx) already referenced.

Comment: Thank you so much, was trying hard what was going wrong, and Firebug helped and here is my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30213504/2218697).

Answer (score 6):

**Note**: my problem was first, i referenced [wrong](http://forums.asp.net/t/1961426.aspx?Ajax+BeginForm+and+UpdateTargetId+not+working) ajax script file `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js` instead of `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` and latest jquery version doesn't worked, [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782697/are-microsoftajax-js-microsoftmvcajax-js-and-microsoftmvcvalidation-js-obsolete)   `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`  worked for me.

i was [trying](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC) to return content after successful entry

so here is the order:

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
```

Post of [Darin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) and  [Richard Everett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1617642/asp-net-axaj-beginform-updatetargetid-not-working.) helped. hope helps.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and solution was:

- Check that
  UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled is true.
- Add reference to
  jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js as Darin
  adviced.

Unfortunatelly, it will not help for you because you set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to false, but can help for somebody.

Comment: I have been working on an MVC4 project where my ajax form used to submit via ajax and then suddenly didn't. I tried all the advice and then finally found your point to set UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled to true. This did the trick. Thanks so much Ivan Sokalskiy.

Answer (score 1):

Late but correct. Make sure to reference the unobtrusive-ajax.js file as well as the MicrosoftAjax.js and MicrosoftMvcAjax.js files in that order.
Works

Answer (score 1):

Besides checking if the .js is referenced, also check if no other form tags are being rendered. In my case, I had another form tag on the master page with the default action that was causing the whole page to reload.

Comment: What if I need the other form too?

Comment: I recommend using [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) if you need to isolate the behavior to specific parts of the page.

Comment: I found out my problem was due to Missing of the include of the bundles/jqueryval  of the ASP.Net MVC Template which includes the unobstructive script.

Answer (score 1):

Notice if you use Asp.Net template like I do, It bundles the file to bundles/jqueryval.
So you have to add

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

to the page.